# What does Window hopping mean?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am reading  tutorial for beginners in [KSQLDb.](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/time-and-windows-in-ksqldb-queries/)

I have faced with table query:

```
CREATE TABLE pageviews_per_region_per_30secs10secs AS
  SELECT regionid,
         count(*)
  FROM pageviews_enriched
  WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 30 SECONDS, ADVANCE BY 10 SECONDS)
  WHERE UCASE(gender)='FEMALE' AND LCASE (regionid) LIKE '%_6'
  GROUP BY regionid
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

Below is definition query:

> The following query is the same query as above that computes the count
> for hopping window of 30 seconds that advances by 10 seconds.

Does it mean to take out data during 30 seconds with 10 seconds delay?

When to use WINDOW HOPPING?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windowing allows you to group records through time. So this works like **GROUP BY** clauses in queries and provides further grouping.

The difference between a Hopping and Tumbling Window is the end time of the aggregation. With **Tumbling Windows**, you are grouping from a start time (WINDOWSTART()) to an end time (WINDOWEND()) in fixed intervals. Once the end time occurs, the start time begins again.

With **Hopping Windows**, the start time does not have to wait for an end time to begin the next window, so windows can overlap. The **SIZE** on Tumbling and Hopping windows is the same, the size, or length of time of the aggregation. The **ADVANCE BY** in Hopping Windows is the delay before starting this next aggregation.

So, an example, if you are aggregating the amount of Female users in region 6, with a Hopping Window, an aggregation datapoint, or Female user page view, can belong to two windows. With a Tumbling Window, the window timeframes are distinct and do not overlap, so the datapoints will only be counted once per timeframe.

There are some nice charts in this [doc](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/time-and-windows-in-ksqldb-queries/) to show how the windows overlap or not through time.

Comment: Could you explain more, Hopping Windows allows to agregate data in time interval and delay between intervals? So, how to interpratate "hopping window of 30 seconds that advances by 10 second". It mean to read events each 30 seconds then wait 10 second and start read next 30 seconds?

Comment: Hopping and tumbling windows both deal with windows or groupings through time but hopping windows have overlaps. So in your example, the 10 seconds is not a gap between the 30 second windows, but it specifies how the windows overlap. See the 'Windowed Aggregation' chart in the link above. Also, for an example of what actual results look like: https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/create-tumbling-windows/ksql.html . It's been a while since I looked at this, but those may clarify the differences

Comment: Thank you. but I can not imaging the case when use it, when data is captured during each 30 seconds with 10 overlap

Comment: https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/create-hopping-windows/ksql.html has a hopping window example with enough detail so you can see yourself in real time. "So what KSQL runs are continuous queries — transformations that run continuously as new data passes through them — on streams of data in Kafka topics. " https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-streaming-sql-for-apache-kafka/ The examples show example output with the 'rating counts' increasing in the same window. Also another useful link on streams: https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/join-a-stream-to-a-table/ksql.html